# How to set up a submit button from sheet 1 to remove the protection on sheet 2 so a new user can input data, and then it will lock back up again

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I have 2 sheets (Sheet 1 & Sheet 2). Sheet 1 is protected besides a few fillable cells, including an apps script button to log the entered data to Sheet 2. Sheet 2 is protected and can not be edited by another user.

I am looking for some assistance to be able to add a script that will unlock Sheet 2 when someone hits the submit button so that the data can be inputted then locks it back up so that only the owner can change the data after it has been inputted by another user.

Comment: What you are looking to do might require a long explanation because of the lack of context as we don't know how much you know about programming, Apps Script, and Google Cloud Platform and how flexible is you design / idea of using a button. You should [edit] the question to make it more specific and to provide enough context. It would be best if you learned how the authorization of Apps Script services works, concepts like active and effective user, get familiar with the limitations of the user interface elements like buttons and triggers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your description seems to assume this algorithm:

1. unlock log sheet
2. write data to log sheet
3. lock log sheet

But unlocking and locking is not possible unless the account *already has write access* to the log sheet. That means that unlocking and locking are actually not needed in the first place.

What you should do is protect the log sheet permanently so that the account the *script* runs under can write to the sheet, while other accounts cannot.

The algorithm them becomes:

1. write data to log sheet

So the question really is how to get a script to run under an write-capable account when it is started by another account.

When a script runs through a button click, it is executed under the account of the user at the keyboard. That means that the script cannot write to the protected sheet. It cannot remove and reconfigure protections that were set by another account either.

To run a script under your account, regardless of the identity of the user at the keyboard, use an [installable "on edit" trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). You can make the trigger run when the user clicks a checkbox or enters a value in a cell.

Alternatively, [create a form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888) for data input. Form responses automatically appear in a separate tab in the spreadsheet in a row-oriented fashion. This way, you do not need to share a spreadsheet in the first place. You can customize a form with at a paid tool such as [Formfacade](https://formfacade.com).

Comment: I've seen people use this:

   `let protection = datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow(),1,1,datasheet.getMaxColumns()).protect();
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
      protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }`

Comment: That would indeed be one way to protect a range. Edited the answer to explain why you do not actually need to programmatically lock and unlock ranges or sheets. You should redesign the way the script is run instead. Alternatively, [create a form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888).

Comment: its more then just a simple form... its like a ui with fillable areas.... so a form would not suit my needs.

With the script above... when run, it will still allow the person who hit submit + the owner to be able to access and edit the changes. Is there a way to restrict it so that only the owner has access to edit and not the submitter?

Comment: Yes, by using an installable trigger. Follow the advice given in the answer.